# Include_once e diretórios direferentes - php

Tags: php, mvc, include

Estou tento problemas com o include em relação aos diretórios, pois quando chamo uma classe de outro diretório que contenha outro include os caminhos são diferentes. Preciso saber se tem alguma maneira de unificar estes includes e sempre chama-los da mesma forma, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Dê exemplos do que ocorre.

Comment: Ou você adiciona no `includepath` ou usa uma espécie de `define(_ROOT_, '/caminho/padrao')`, e inclui arquivos sempre usando `include _ROOT_ . "/caminho/arquivo.php";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você não use *namespaces*, a melhor maneira disso é sempre levar em conta o caminho absoluto dos arquivos do sistema, e não os caminhos relativos – ou seja, o caminho de um arquivo em relação a outro.

Além disso, use sempre as seguintes constantes mágicas, a fim de facilitar a inclusão de arquivos:

- `__FILE__` (para referenciar o arquivo atual), e
- `__DIR__` (para referenciar o diretório do arquivo atual).

Por exemplo:

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php');
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/config/config.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/url_router.php');
```

Agora, se você usa a versão 5.3 do PHP ou maior, de repente vale a pena começar a pensar em namespaces. Assim, ao invés de incluir os arquivos manualmente, a organização das classes leva em conta a estrutura de diretórios – o que fica muito mais intuitivo.

Se você optar por esse caminho, é uma boa usar o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), que pode gerar um arquivo de autoload e facilita alguns aspectos do desenvolvimento da sua aplicação.

Comment: Um detalhe à parte: a constante mágica (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` só está disponível a partir do PHP 5.3. A melhor opção, para aumentar a portabilidade, é utilizar `dirname(__FILE__)` en vez de `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso lhe ajude.
No php set_include_path() verifica o primeiro caminho, e se não encontrá-lo, verifique o seguinte caminho, até que ele seja localize o arquivo incluído ou retorna com um aviso ou um erro. Você pode modificar ou definir o seu caminho de inclusão em tempo de execução usando set_include_path(). Veja:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'diretorio');
```

veja [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295164/set-include-pathget-include-path-path-separator-phpseclib)

Mas, também você precisa conhercer o autoload() nativo do php.